# Need to integrate Python Interpreter in Web Page which POST's the code to my Server which executes it

Tags: python, frontend, backend

I have a Web Page, that has a text field where one can write Python code. I want to send a JSON POST request having code as a key value pair where code being my value to my Backend Server. My backend should extract this code from JSON and place it in a Python (.py) file that can be executed later.

What is the best way to achieve this.

1. Is there a Python Interpreter which can be integrated in the WebPage. That provides me with the valid Python code at backend.
2. Is there a way to capture Formatted Code from Text Box and send it to the backed while preserving the Indentation for valid Python code.

Comment: What are you running in the backend? Which language? The `python` tag is not really relevant as the important language in this case is the backend's one. You will have to do your second proposed solution and edit your backend to do the rest.

Comment: Plenty of python web frameworks out there. If however you want to execute python code from user input, you must take security into account and rely on a microservice living on a different server and ideally in a container. Alternatively you can use an AWS lambda function or google cloud function which will probably the easiest approach.